# Cannot install into target mounted with noexec or nodev while doing qemu-deboot strapping

Tags: mount, virtualization, fstab, chroot

I'm trying to install the armel version of Ubuntu with qemu-deboot-strap on my desktop X64 system,but I've found this error :

```
$ mkdir precise

$ sudo qemu-debootstrap --arch=armel precise ./precise/
```

I: Running command:

```
 $ debootstrap --arch armel --foreign precise ./precise/
 /usr/sbin/debootstrap: 1280: /usr/sbin/debootstrap: cannot create  /media/ziomario/Nexus-10/Images/313/precise/test-dev-null: Permission denied

E: Cannot install into target '/media/ziomario/Nexus-10/Images/313/precise' mounted with noexec or nodev
```

do you know how to fix it ? my system is like this :

```
Linux ziomario-Macmini 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and this is the content of the `/etc/fstab` file :

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

/ was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c703f96e-42fd-4734-b622-15ba1dd5fc21 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=1c2b872f-3be3-4c6c-b021-6cec3e8b77e2 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to bootstrap into your mounted nexus 10 data directory?

Comment: The answer http://superuser.com/a/620180/298426 to http://superuser.com/questions/620003/debootstrap-error-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring should solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

Remounting with `exec` and `dev` is the solution. If your filesystem is encrypted, you also need to pass `-i` to mount.

```
 sudo mount -i -o remount,exec,dev /home/user
```

Where in my case `/home/user/` is my encrypted home directory. After that debootstrap had no issues any more.

I found this answer [here on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/620003/debootstrap-error-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring) and it worked for me.

Comment: what? "mount: /home/thetechrobo: can't find in /etc/fstab."